# C++ equivalent of C# SpinWait.SpinUntil

Tags: c#, c++

I am in the need of spinning a thread until a specific condition appears.

In c# I had good experience with `SpinWait`.

However being somewhat new to C++ I am unsure what the equivalent to this would be:

```
    SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => myCondition == true);
```

I tried sleeping, yielding and looping without any but I cannot get the same performance in my C++ application that I had with c# SpinWait.

I am using VS 2017 and the VC++ compiler.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: `while(!myCondition) { std::this_thread::yeild(); }` is probably the closest you'll get.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I tried that but CPU workload wise the C# SpinWait did perform better than yielding.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the source for [`SpinOnce`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SpinWait.cs,1680c35f6ce0f3ea)? It seems `SpinUntil` calls `SpinOnce` which then calls `Sleep(0)` and `Sleep(1)` every so many calls to `yield`.

Comment: @NetMage Okay so decompiling the Net Source and implementing it on my own it is.

Comment: would you consider sharing the result?

Answer (score -2):

Using synchronization objects like events is what you are looking for. Just attach yourself to an event and setevent from where you are want to back again.

Comment: This is not answer to the question! It is useless comment.